# javafx with Scene Builder cannot getText from textField

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am a starter of javafx. I am trying to create a form which can store the input by clicking a button. However, it has error and I cannot proceed.
Here is my code:

In fxml file:

```
 <VBox prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ass.InputDataController">
   <children>
      <Label text=" Input" />
      <TextField id="Input" fx:id="Input" onAction="#handleButtonAction" />
      <Button fx:id="enter" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="707.0" text="Enter" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

In InputDataController.java:

```
  public class InputDataController implements Initializable {
  @FXML
  private TextField Input;
  @FXML
  private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
     String t = Input->getText();
  }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    }
}
```

The error say:

```
error: incompatible types: String is not a functional interface
        String t = Input->getText();
```

I have tried to implement another function:

```
@FunctionalInterface
    interface String {
        String getText(TextField t);
    }
```

But it still states that:

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

Is there any method to solve this problem? It will be better if I don't have to implement a functional interface!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
String t = Input.getText();
```

(In Java, *all* objects are accessed via references, so there is no need for different dereferencing operators `.` and `->` to distinguish between references and pointers, as in other languages. You access a member of an object with `reference.member`. The `->` operator in Java is used to define a "lambda expression" which can be assigned to a type that is a functional interface (an interface with a single abstract method), which is why the compiler complained that you were assigning this to something that wasn't a functional interface.)